# How to get object ID in jQuery and combine it with other string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using qtip2 jQuery plugin to show tooltip for an image map. All areas have ids assigned, and the content for each tooltip has id of "area-id"+"-text".
Example:

```
<area id="1" coords="159,32,255,2" shape="poly" href="#" />
<p id="1-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the content for each tooltip by getting area's id and adding "-text" suffix. Here's the example how the syntax for the plugin looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/G2sqU/

Right now I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var myId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery('area').qtip({
        content: {
            text: ('#' + myId + '-text')
        },
        position: {
            style: {
                classes: 'dealer'
            },
            target: 'mouse',
            adjust: {
                mouse: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But the tooltip content appears as "#undefined-text" - apparently my method doesn't work?

Does anyone has any suiggestions how to fix the code above?

Comment: `this` is the `document` object inside a DOM ready handler, so getting `attr('id')` of `document` will be undefined.

Comment: try area instead of this

Comment: @Abhishek Prakash: I think we can assume there may be multiple `area`s as he said `"all areas have..."` :)

Comment: Absolutely, I am in total agreement with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the `document` object inside a DOM ready handler, so getting `attr('id')` of `document` will be undefined.

You need to apply `qtip` to each `area` using an `each` loop, so that you have a context for each `area` element. You can then apply `qtip` with the appropriate settings for each `area`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('area').each(function () {
        var myId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $('#' + myId + '-text').text()
            },
            position: {
                style: {
                    classes: 'dealer'
                },
                target: 'mouse',
                adjust: {
                    mouse: false
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Update:**

Note: you can use the following shortcut *DOM ready handler* to provide a locally scoped `$` and shorten your code to the traditional jQuery use of `$` (without clashes):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('area').each(function () {
        var myId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $('#' + myId + '-text').text()
            },
            position: {
                style: {
                    classes: 'dealer'
                },
                target: 'mouse',
                adjust: {
                    mouse: false
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the text bit is probably meant to be `$('#' + myId + '-text').text()`. (I have my mind-reading hat on today)

Comment: @Jamiec: Good pickup - edited (but you already knew I was going to do that...) :)

Comment: Thanks! That works flawlessly!
And thanks for the locally scoped 'code'$'code'. The site is on Wordpress with jQuery in noConflict mode.

Comment: Also, I've trimmed down the last .text() as I wanted the content with all the tagging (links, text formatting, etc.)

Anyway, thanks a mil!